# GSON JSON output has additional quotes and back slashes

Tags: json, gson, escaping

I am moving from Jackson to GSON. When I switched to GSON; the output i receive has additional double quotes and back slashes as shown below :

```
"{\"\"categoryNames\":[
  \"ABC Catergroy 999\",
   \"Category 111\",\"]}"
```

I want it as just JSON proper format like

```
{"categoryNames":[
  "ABC Catergroy 999",
  "Category 111" ]}
```

How can i fix this? I know that behind the scenes GSON "JSONWriter" class is adding the quotes and back slashes. How to get rid of this?